# Why are the Keycloak security constraints not active in @SpringBootTest and how can I activate them?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, keycloak

I'm in the process of building a new microservice and securing it with access tokens from Keycloak. So far I've been successful, the endpoint /token/test is only accessible with a valid token from Keycloak, the application properties look like this:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8888/auth
keycloak.realm=realm
keycloak.resource=api
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0]=basic-token
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name=secured by basic access token
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/*
```

This is working fine when starting the project with mvn spring-boot:run (I'm using spring-boot-starter, keycloak-spring-boot-starter and **without** spring-boot-starter-security which I want to avoid if possible.

Now I'm writing some tests for the fun of it and Keycloak's security constraints are simply not working. I've followed the test setup from https://github.com/cremich/testcontainers-keycloak (with updated versions and JUnit 5), the only difference being that the example is doing a lot of Keycloak setup by hand using spring-boot-starter-security. Why does it only work in tests when done with -security and why does my way not seem to work?

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Edit: [Example project](https://github.com/N4zroth/keycloak-test-demo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of debugging, I finally figured it out. The problem is that Keycloak's authentication is (for whatever reason, lol) done in a Tomcat valve, not in a filter. MockMvc doesn't go through the servlet container (and its valves), so it never even reaches the point where it would be authenticated.

TestRestTemplate does, though (and if you use starter-security, it is also a filter not a valve). I don't know the design decision behind using a valve and not a filter but you can either use the configuration from keycloak-starter and test it with a TestRestTemplate or use the more 'expensive' starter-security configuration in combination with MockMvc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the authentication in SecurityContext with a mock or instance of the right type in each test: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication)`

I wrote a set of [libs to ease this](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons). It includes a `@WithMockKeycloackAuth` annotation, along with Keycloak dedicated `MockMvc` request post-processor and `WebTestClient` configurer / mutator

Sample `@WithMockKeycloackAuth` usage:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = GreetingController.class)
@Import({
        ServletKeycloakAuthUnitTestingSupport.UnitTestConfig.class,
        KeycloakSpringBootSampleApp.KeycloakConfig.class })
// because this sample stands in the middle of non spring-boot-keycloak projects, keycloakproperties are isolated in
// application-keycloak.properties
@ActiveProfiles("keycloak")
public class GreetingControllerAnnotatedTest {
    private static final String GREETING = "Hello %s! You are granted with %s.";

    @MockBean
    MessageService messageService;

    @MockBean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    @Autowired
    MockMvcSupport api;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        when(messageService.greet(any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
            final var auth = invocation.getArgument(0, Authentication.class);
            return String.format(GREETING, auth.getName(), auth.getAuthorities());
        });
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockKeycloakAuth
    public void whenAuthenticatedWithoutAuthorizedPersonnelThenSecuredRouteIsForbidden() throws Exception {
        api.get("/secured-route").andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockKeycloakAuth({ "AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL" })
    public void whenAuthenticatedWithAuthorizedPersonnelThenSecuredRouteIsOk() throws Exception {
        api.get("/secured-route").andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockKeycloakAuth(
            authorities = { "USER", "AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL" },
            id = @IdTokenClaims(sub = "42"),
            oidc = @OidcStandardClaims(
                    email = "ch4mp@c4-soft.com",
                    emailVerified = true,
                    nickName = "Tonton-Pirate",
                    preferredUsername = "ch4mpy"),
            accessToken = @KeycloakAccessToken(
                    realmAccess = @KeycloakAccess(roles = { "TESTER" }),
                    authorization = @KeycloakAuthorization(
                            permissions = @KeycloakPermission(rsid = "toto", rsname = "truc", scopes = "abracadabra"))),
            privateClaims = @ClaimSet(stringClaims = @StringClaim(name = "foo", value = "bar")))
    public void whenAuthenticatedWithKeycloakAuthenticationTokenThenCanGreet() throws Exception {
        api.get("/greet")
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(startsWith("Hello ch4mpy! You are granted with ")))
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL")))
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("USER")))
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("TESTER")));
    }
}
```

Different libs are available from maven-central, choose one of following according to your use-case:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-test-addons</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.4</version>
  <scope>test</test>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-test-webmvc-addons</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.4</version>
  <scope>test</test>
</dependency>
```